# changing the key preview background layout for android soft keyboard

Tags: android, android-layout, android-softkeyboard

I am making a soft keyboard for android and I want to change the key preview layout of the soft keyboard.

I added "keyPreviewLayout" attribute for input.xml and I also created the keypreview.xml (for the layout) and previewbackground.xml (for the layout background) for this. both files are look like this.

keypreview.xml

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<TextView xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:background="@drawable/previewbackground"
    android:textColor="@android:color/white"
    android:gravity="center"
    android:textSize="32sp" />
```

previewbackground.xml

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<shape xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"> 
    <stroke android:width="1dp" android:color="#bbFFFFFF" /> 
    <solid android:color="#FF000000"/>
</shape>
```

and I got like a preview, which the wrapped the background to text length.

this background is quite silly, so I want a key preview background like in other keyboards.

tell me a method to get this.

Comment: sorry for my english, if i had a mistake, please correct them.

Comment: and this is about the key feedback layout, not the key layout of the soft keyboard.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Finally, I got through it.

"You can change the key preview width, but not height."

I forgot to add `android:width` for keypreview.xml to change the width of the preview.

Sorry for that.